# Jquery $.ajax post doesn't post on i.e.?

Tags: jquery

i have a **login.php** page:

```
                        echo '<div id="wpass" style="display:none">Wrong Pass...<br /></div>';
                        echo '<div id="redirect" style="display:none"> &nbsp;<img src="http://www.myurl.com/inc/media/photos/redirect.gif" /></div>';
                        echo '<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" size="10">';
                        echo '<input type="submit" name="giris" id="giris" value="GIRIS">';
```

This is my **jquery code**:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#giris').click(function(){
         $('#wpass').hide();
         $('#redirect').show();
         var pass = $('#pass').val();
         $(this).attr("disabled", true);
         $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"login_action.php",
             data: {
                 pass: pass
             },
             success:function(html){
                 if(html=='true'){
                     window.location="http://www.myurl.com/news.php";
                 }
                 if(html=='false'){
                     $('#redirect').hide();
                     $('#wpass').show();
                     $('#giris').attr("disabled", false);
                 }
             }
         });
     });  
});
```

and this is **login_action.php**:

```
$sifre = '123456'; // for example
$gelen_sifre = @$_POST['pass'];
if($sifre == $gelen_sifre){
    echo 'true';
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['admin'] = "true";
    $_SESSION['giris'] = "true";
}else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

well. This works on chrome and mozilla firefox but does not work on i.e. 11

it returns nothing (no 'true' or 'false'). So its trying to login...

i think i can not post data on i.e by this way.

What can i do?

Comment: Did you try having the PHP return 1 for true and 0 for false? And changing javascript (html=='true') to (html) and if(html=='false') to else. Thereby not depending on different browsers to property read the php flags.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code; it looks good the request should be being made - you can check log files.

Comment: Is there any error you can see on console (developer tools)?

Answer (score 0):

No error, posts empty text. I couldn't solve that.

I hate I.E.

**My best solution:**

```
function get_browser(){
    var N=navigator.appName, ua=navigator.userAgent, tem;
    var M=ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
    if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
    M=M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    return M[0];
}


$('body').ready(function(){
    var browser = get_browser();
       if(browser == 'Netscape'){
           window.location="http://www.lalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala.com/";
       }
});
```